# How to send a company I want to join a tailored project without coming off as brash?

Tags: professionalism, applications, unprofessional-behavior

I built a demo project for a company I want to join. Basically it's a dedicated marketing project in which I built it as if it was done by the company itself (with the logos and everything).

I thought it would be helpful for me to build a tailored project to both show my interest and the value I could bring to them.

I'm planning to send an email to the marketing manager, but I'm afraid I'll be misunderstood as someone who's overly confident and making adjustments to the way they do business.

How to communicate my passion without coming off as brash?

Comment: `with the logos and everything` is... dangerous. Most logos are trademarked and using them without the company's consent can be subject to legal actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good idea.

It shows initiative (because you made your own project for them), competence (assuming it looks good), and passion (you want to work with *them* so you made a relevant project).

No halfway useful marketing - or any - manager would ever disregard this.

Another word of advice - don't worry about appearing brash *the higher up the org  chart you go*. Low level managers (and non-management staff) will always get upset by brashness, including saying their current strategy is crap.

High level managers, however, almost universally got there by challenging the status-quo and creating the new from the old. They *want* people who say that the current stategy is bad *and here is how to fix it*.

I only mention this as something to consider who to apply to. If you feel you are attacking somewhat their current strategy, then send it to someone higher in the org chart. If you feel it corresponds to their strategy, then someone lower is ok (although, someone higher is also good too!).

all the best, and good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Every industry, type of position, company and culture look at these kinds of things differently. You need to do some research on this company and get a better idea what they're like.

If they think you're being to brash, do you really want to work for a company like that? It's possible you won't like working there.

There are worse things that could happen:

1. They think your project is so poorly done, they will severely
   criticize you to the point where you'll think you need to change
   professions.
2. They're completely ignore it because they probably post the proper way to apply for a position on their website. Those who can't comply are seen as being less competent than creative.
3. They'll provide critical feedback and see how you handle it. Do you get defensive? Do you just give in and agree with them? Can you apply the feedback to making it better? Not being able to handle criticism is one sign of being brash.

Who knows, they may love it, but you're better off finding out more about this company and the people who run it. Hopefully, they've blogged or been interviewed and can provide some insight on what kinds of work they do and the people they want working for them.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a fine line between proactive and arrogant, creative and annoying.**

I would recommend to err on the side of caution unless you are 99% certain that you can allow yourself to be a little bold in a particular situation, OR feel that you just HAVE TO take a one-in-a-million shot to set yourself apart from the intense competition for a coveted spot.

Why don't you apply for a job first, and either include a link to your project with your application materials (resume, cover letter) and/or (if you get an interview) bring it to the interview?

That way you leave to the managers the choice of whether to look at your project, but since you have it, you can point to it when the moment is right as something that sets you apart from the rest and shows your interest and dedication.

Whatever the case, you want to approach this with humility and ask their permission to show them what you've done before you actually do. One exception would be if the company is a small start-up where communication is a lot more straight-forward and dynamic, with less emphasis on 'due process'. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I assume you're looking for a marketing role? is there a role they actively recruiting for?

If there is then apply in through whatever their standard channels are and include the project in your portfolio/samples. You can make mention of it in your cover letter.

If this isn't for an advertised role and you're just speculatively pitching then yeah sending it to the marketing manager along with a wider portfolio should be fine, just try and downplay it in the cover letter as you don't want to come across as insinuating that you think their current marketing materials are crap! If the work is good quality that will speak for itself and they will be more likely to appreciate that you obviously spent some time on them specifically and that it's not a scattergun pitch.

Comment: terrible idea. applying through "the standard channels" is for people with no initiative. might as well just spend time crafting your CV and then send it straight to the recycle bin

Comment: @bharal couldn't disagree more.. IMO applying outside the standard channels for an advertised role doesn't show initiative it shows either an inability to understand simple instructions or a complete disregard for a company's process. I can only speak for myself but when I'm hiring the candidates who work with what I've setup to make the process easier for me get careful attention, those who can't be bothered or think they are too "special" to get binned.